# Can I use SpringData by itself

Tags: spring-data

I'm interested if it's possible to use SpringData without Spring. For instance the same way you would use hibernate? Is this possible? My use case is in serverless computing, whereby I don't want to create an entire Spring Context but just make use of Spring Data. I don't what there to be any real initiation process either as in a complex tree of objects needing to be constructed with each request.

Comment: http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/#quick-start

Comment: Your example has spring-boot, I want to use it without need to start up Spring.

Comment: "I don't what there to be any real initiation process" both Spring Data and any JPA implementations create a fair amount of stuff during startup. The only way to avoid that is not to use it.